# Pass a string to stored procedure as parameter with Identity ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure like below that I passed a string as a parameter to it :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddWantedJob
    (@JTID int ,
     @LocationID int,
     @OpeningDate datetime,
     @closingDate datetime,
     @JobDesc nvarchar(max),
     @InputQuery NVARCHAR(500))
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @JobID AS INT
    DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(2000)

    SET @QueryString = 'insert into WantedJobWorkType (JobID , WTID ) values '
    SET @QueryString = @QueryString + @InputQuery

    INSERT INTO WantedJobs (JTID, LocationID, OpeningDate, closingDate, JobDesc) 
    VALUES (@JTID, @LocationID, @OpeningDate, @closingDate, @JobDesc)

    SET @JobID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    EXEC (@QueryString)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

I passed string like `(@JobID, 1), (@JobID, 2 )` to it, but I get an error, why?

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@JobID".

Comment: @Ivan Starostin , I put it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrize your Dynamic query execution

```
SET @QueryString = 'insert into WantedJobWorkType (JobID , WTID ) values '
SET @QueryString = @QueryString + @InputQuery 

INSERT INTO WantedJobs (JTID , LocationID , OpeningDate ,closingDate , JobDesc ) 
VALUES (@JTID , @LocationID , @OpeningDate ,@closingDate , @JobDesc)
SET @JobID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

EXEC sp_executesql @QueryString,N'@JobID INT',@JobID = @JobID
```

But you can pass the 1 and 2 alone in Input string instead of `(@JobID , 1) , (@JobID , 2)`. Then split the values and insert it with generated identity value. It will avoid dynamic part